# SharePoint Document Information Panel and Word Save Functionality

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a Custom Document Information Panel on a Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Document Library. In the DIP, I have fields in which custom InfoPath rules have been written to validate certain fields. For example there is a From Date and To Date where an InfoPath rule validates that To Date should be greater than From Date. The validation rule also highlights the box which has an error.

Now the issue is, when the user presses Save, word validates only REQUIRED properties and does not respect the DIP validation errors, which means the user can still go ahead and save the document into the document library.

**How do we avoid this? Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

Try with events on those date fields. If there are dates that don't get satisfied, just clear those fields so word won't be able to save it. You could do it also by rules.